# Headphones output mono audio

Tags: headphones, 16.10

I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu GNOME(16.10). The pair of headphones was working fine until few days ago. I am now getting noise and distortion. This doesn't happen to the speaker of my laptop. I've tested the headphones on my other device and they worked fine.

I found out that the headphones are now outputting mono audio instead of stereo audio. 2 channels are getting mixed together and causes distortion. When I test the speaker I'm hearing "front left" from both sides of my headphones. If I balance the sound to the left or right, I cannot hear the sound from a single channel. For example, if I move the pointer to the left, I'm able to hear "front left" from both sides but I cannot hear "front right".

I have not changed anything. This problem occurred suddenly when I was playing musics in `Rhythmbox`. `Analog Stereo Output` is the only profile I can select. Please help me to fix this problem.